# Can i use the Same form to input different cells

Tags: forms, vba, excel, duplicates

I am quite new to VBA and wanted to see if i was going about my task the long way.

I need to ask users questions and am using a VBA form to do so, once they input there answers this will then save to the workbook in the specified cells.

However they will need to answer the same questions for each country, the questions will stay the same, but values, and cell locations differ. Is there a way to do this without creating 50 identical forms?

I should also mention that data will be prefilled from when they answered the questions previously which eliminates the ability of adding to the next blank row.

Comment: I should also mention that data will be prefilled from when they answered the questions previously which eliminates the ability of adding to the next blank row.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I'm sure the community will provide a variety.

Comment: Where is your list of countries coming from?  Is it on a worksheet or is it hard coded?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the countries listed on a worksheet in column A.

```
Sub PostAnswer(Country as string)
Dim lrow As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lrow = 1
    Do While lrow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Check if this row is the current country 
        If ws.Range("A" & lrow).Value = Country Then
            'Write the answers to the current row
            ws.Range("B" & lrow).Value = SomeAnswer
            ws.Range("C" & lrow).Value = SomeOtherPartOfTheAnswer
            ws.Range("D" & lrow).Value = SomeOtherPartOfTheAnswer
            Exit Do
        End If

    lrow = lrow + 1
    Loop
End sub
```

I am assuming you have a button like "Post Answer" or something on the form.
In the button click event call the above sub passing it the current country.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    PostAnswer "Current Country"
End sub
```